# How to convert a column containing sequence of numbers into sequence of alphabets in Pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

How to convert a column containing sequence of numbers into another column with sequence of alphabets against it e.g., 0 as a, 1 as b likewise. Since numbers would range from 0-9 so does alphabets from a-j respectively. Please help.

Input

| ssn_num |
| --- |
| 1342 |
| 4321 |
| 2133 |

expected output

| ssn_num | alpha_op |
| --- | --- |
| 1342 | bdec |
| 4321 | edcb |
| 2133 | cbdd |

Comment: how do you understand it is 1-3-4-2 and not 13-4-2?

Comment: numbers should range from 0-9 and alphabets from a-j respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the column then transform each digit to an ascii code point in the range (97-122) and finally convert the ascii code back to a character.

```
df = df.withColumn('alpha_op', F.expr("array_join(transform(split(ssn_num, ''), x -> char(97 + cast(x as integer))), '')"))
```

---

```
+-------+--------+
|ssn_num|alpha_op|
+-------+--------+
|   1342|    bdec|
|   4321|    edcb|
|   2133|    cbdd|
+-------+--------+
```